# pygame.display.update() causing periodic lag spikes

Tags: python, pygame

I made a simple program with Pygame that was basically a scrolling background and noticed periodic lag spikes. After messing with the code for a long time, I found out that calls to pygame.display.update() would sometimes take a lot longer to execute.

To really strip down and replicate the problem, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

FRAME_RATE = 30

# don't mind the screen and time_passed variables; they aren't used in this script

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    prev_spike = 0
    time_passed = 0
    while 1:
        start = time.clock()
        pygame.display.update()
        timenow = time.clock()
        time_spent = timenow - start
        if time_spent > 0.01:
            print time_spent 
            if prev_spike:
                print "Last spike was: {} seconds ago".format(timenow - prev_spike)
            prev_spike = timenow
        time_passed = clock.tick(FRAME_RATE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_game()
```

A snippet of output at that framerate:

```
0.0258948412828
Last spike was: 1.01579813191 seconds ago
0.0186809297657
Last spike was: 0.982841934526 seconds ago
0.0225958783907
Last spike was: 2.01697784257 seconds ago
0.0145269648427
Last spike was: 1.01603407404 seconds ago
0.0186094554386
Last spike was: 2.01713885195 seconds ago
0.0283046020628
Last spike was: 1.03270104172 seconds ago
0.0223322687757
Last spike was: 1.01709735072 seconds ago
0.0152536205013
Last spike was: 1.01601639759 seconds ago
```

I've really no clue what's going on, and would really love some insight.

Some more details:

A snippet of the output when printing the time_spent in every loop iteration (instead of only when it was > 0.01):

```
0.000204431946257
0.000242090462673
0.000207890381438
0.000272447838151
0.000230178074828
0.0357667523718          <-- update taking two orders of magnitude longer than normal
0.000293582719813
0.000343153624075
0.000287818661178
0.000249391603611
```

When run at 60 FPS, the interval between each spike almost always be 1 second, very rarely 2 seconds (and the spikes would last about twice as long). At lower frame rates, the interval between spikes would start to vary more, but would always be close to a whole number in value.

I tried running the script on another computer, but the problem wasn't replicated; the execution time on pygame.display.update() was reasonably quick and consistent. However, when I ran my original program on that machine, the one-second-interval lag spikes remained (I'll probably look for other machines to test on...)

Both machines that I tested on ran Windows 7.

EDIT:

I grabbed a few random games hosted on the Pygame website and I'm getting similar behaviour - calls to `pygame.display.update` (or `flip`) periodically take between 10 - 40 ms, whereas they normally take less than 2 ms.

Nobody else seems to be having this problem (or complaining about, at it least. That could be because most games run on less than 30 FPS where this issue isn't too noticeable), so there's likely something off with my environment. I did (kinda) reproduce the issue on a second machine though (as described above), so I'd rather not ignore the problem and hope end users don't experience it...

Comment: I don't have a direct answer, but these are good resources for timestep issues : http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ , http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step

Comment: @monkey Thanks for the links. Using a dt would prevent this problem from affecting the game/simulation, but the problem itself is still unsolved. I guess I can just hope the user doesn't notice the stuttering or something.

Comment: Since you're using pygame, you can get current elapsed time from `pygame.time.get_ticks()` http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks

Comment: I tested your code on 
- python 2.7.2
pygame 1.9.1release, windows 7, got not problem, time_spent always around 0.0004~5

Comment: Try pygame.display.flip()

Answer (score 2):

**[Try asking this in Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)** and you might get a better answer.

**EDIT: The following code doesn't seem to fix the issues raised, but does provide testing for animation and uses timed callbacks for main game loop**

Try working with a timed callback to your render function.

```
import pygame
import time
import math
from pygame.locals import *

desiredfps = 60
updaterate = int(1000 / desiredfps)
print "Aiming for {0}fps, update every {1} millisecond".format(desiredfps, updaterate)
lasttime = 0
rectx = 0
recty = 0

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, updaterate)

    def mainloop():
        global lasttime
        global rectx
        global recty
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("red"), pygame.Rect(rectx,recty,20,20))
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("blue"), pygame.Rect(480-rectx,480-recty,20,20))
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("green"), pygame.Rect(rectx,480-recty,20,20))
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("yellow"), pygame.Rect(480-rectx,recty,20,20))
        rectx += 5
        if rectx > 500:
            rectx = 0
            recty += 20
        beforerender = time.clock()
        pygame.display.update()
        afterrender = time.clock()
        renderdelta = afterrender - beforerender
        framedelta = beforerender - lasttime
        lasttime = beforerender
        if renderdelta > 0.01:
            print "render time: {0}".format(renderdelta)
            print "frame delta: {0}".format(framedelta)
            print "-------------------------------------"            
    while(1):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == USEREVENT+1:
                mainloop()
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return
# Run test           
run_game()
```

I don't seem to have any trouble when doing this, but please let me know if you still experience issues.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Reported frame time has no lag spikes, yet visually (I have added moving object) the lags are very clear.

Comment: Hmm.. Try that edit. It just has really basic animation. If you still get visible lag then I have no idea, otherwise it might be your animations.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, here are some of the results. First, to answer the question:
The cause of lag spikes is not pygame.display.update(). The cause of lag spikes is clock.tick(FRAME_RATE). Note, that clock.tick() without the FRAME_RATE parameter doesn't cause spikes. The problem did not go away when I tried to substitute pygame's clock.tick() with manual tracking of frame rate using python's time.sleep() method. I think it is because internally, both python's time.sleep() and pygame's clock.tick() use the same function, which is known to be imprecise. It seems that if you feed that function 1ms to sleep (so as to not hog all of the CPU if the game is simple enough), the function will sometimes sleep much longer than that, about 10-15ms longer. It depends on the OS implementation of the sleep mechanism and the scheduling involved.

The solution is to not use any sleep-related functions.

There is also a second part. Even if you don't use any sleep(), there is an issue of an inconsistent delta time between individual frames, which when not taken into account may cause visual jittering/stuttering. I believe that this issue has been explored in great detail in this [tutorial](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/).

So I went ahead and implemented the solution presented in this tutorial in python and pygame, and it works perfectly. It looks very smooth even though I'm updating "physics" at only 30fps. It eats a lot of cpu, but it looks nice. Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import division
import pygame
from random import randint
from math import fabs

PHYS_FPS = 30
DT = 1 / PHYS_FPS
MAX_FRAMETIME = 0.25



def interpolate(star1, star2, alpha):
    x1 = star1[0]
    x2 = star2[0]
    # since I "teleport" stars at the end of the screen, I need to ignore
    # interpolation in such cases. try 1000 instead of 100 and see what happens
    if fabs(x2 - x1) < 100:
        return (x2 * alpha + x1 * (1 - alpha), star1[1], star1[2])
    return star2


def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

    # generate stars
    stars = [(randint(0, 500), randint(0, 500), randint(2, 6)) for i in range(50)]
    stars_prev = stars

    accumulator = 0
    frametime = clock.tick()

    play = True
    while play:
        frametime = clock.tick() / 1000
        if frametime > MAX_FRAMETIME:
            frametime = MAX_FRAMETIME

        accumulator += frametime

        # handle events to quit on 'X' and escape key
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                play = False
            elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    play = False

        while accumulator >= DT:
            stars_prev = stars[:]
            # move stars
            for i, (x, y, r) in enumerate(stars):
                stars[i] = (x - r * 50 * DT, y, r) if x > -20 else (520, randint(0, 500), r)
            accumulator -= DT

        alpha = accumulator / DT
        stars_inter = [interpolate(s1, s2, alpha) for s1, s2 in zip(stars_prev, stars)]

        # clear screen
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('black'))

        # draw stars
        for x, y, r in stars_inter:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color('white'), (int(x), y), r)

        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_game()
```

Comment: Yes, `pygame.Clock.tick()` is not accurate, since it just uses `SDL_Delay `. `pygame.Clock.tick_busy_loop()` is more accurate, but wastes more CPU power.

Comment: Updated with working pygame code, with interpolation and other nice things.

Comment: That's awesome, but unfortunately I don't think this answer applies to my problem. I tried your code (and the other answer's code) on my machine and the spikes remain. The code I provided measures the time taken for update() to execute, so there's no room for tick() to mess with anything.

Comment: Then I guess I can't help you much by doing, as I can't reproduce the update() spikes. Try it with SDL and see if the spikes remain. If they do, profile it with SDL's source code (so it shows you the calls update() does and their timing).

Answer (score -2):

```
import pygame
import time
import math
from pygame.locals import *
desiredfps = 60
updaterate = int(1000 / desiredfps)
lasttime = 0
rectx = 0
recty = 0

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, updaterate)
    def mainloop():
        global lasttime
        global rectx
        global recty
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("red"), pygame.Rect(rectx,recty,20,20))
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("blue"), pygame.Rect(480-rectx,480-recty,20,20))
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("green"), pygame.Rect(rectx,480-recty,20,20))
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("yellow"), pygame.Rect(480-rectx,recty,20,20))
        rectx += 5
        if rectx > 500:
            rectx = 0
            recty += 20
        beforerender = time.clock()
        pygame.display.update()
        afterrender = time.clock()
        renderdelta = afterrender - beforerender
        framedelta = beforerender - lasttime
        lasttime = beforerender
        if renderdelta > 0.01:
            print ("render time: {0}").format(renderdelta)
            print ("frame delta: {0}").format(framedelta)
            print ("-------------------------------------")      

    while(1):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == USEREVENT+1:
                mainloop()
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return #
```

Comment: No explanation, no text, only code. Is this supposed to answer the question?